# Google Translate Bar moving content down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-translate

Is there a way to stop Google Translate Bar from moving my content down? I have a static background image, and a header image that corresponds with the background image, so when the Google Translate Bar is fixed to the top of my screen, it moves my top content down and out of the background image.

Is there a way to make it just statically over my content or fixed in such a way it won't move my content down?

Or Can I detect is Translation is taking place, then move my background accordingly? I tried to use this but it doesn't revert back if I remove the Translation Bar:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function (e) {
if(e.target.tagName === 'HTML' && window.google) {
        if(e.target.className.match('translated')) {
            document.body.style.backgroundPosition="0px 40px";
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundPosition="0px 0px";
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: your addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified') code helped me :) ... I have a fixed menu but when google translation appear and disapear it didn't moved my menu. whit this code it's thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult without a code example, but the easiest solution would be to set `position: fixed;` and `top: 0` on the translate bar, however, this means it will always remain at the top of the page once you scroll down.

If the translate bar is near the top of your document, which it sounds like it is, you can set the position to `absolute` instead, keeping the `top: 0` declaration. This should make it appear at the top of the closest *positioned* ancestor, i.e. an element with position set to `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`, or `sticky`. If this doesn't exist, it'll be positioned according to the root tag, i.e. `<html>` in a well-formed document. Here, you could set `position: relative` on your `<body>`, for example.

Both `fixed` and `sticky` takes the element entirely out of the document flow, so they will do exactly what you're requesting here: appear on top of other content.

Answer (score 0):

The addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified') is outdated. What you want is to use DOM MutationObserver Events to apply the change. This DOM API is available on all major browser since 2012 I think.

I use this on to lower the google translator bar, so maybe moving the bar down also solves your problem. If not, just change the callback function and variables for your need.
The google translator creates an iframe element like this:

```
<iframe id=":1.container" class="goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate" frameborder="0" src="javascript:''" style="visibility: visible; top: calc(100% - 40px);">...</iframe>
```

So the MutationObserver code to move that element down is as follow:

```
//Observer for Google translator bar creation and action to move to bottom
// Select the nodetree that will be observed for mutations
var nodetree = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
// Select the target node atributes (CSS selector)
var targetNode = "iframe.goog-te-banner-frame";
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true };
// Callback function to execute when mutations of DOM tree are observed
var lowerGoogleTranslateBar = function(mutations_on_DOMtree) {
    for(var mutation of mutations_on_DOMtree) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log(mutation);
            if (document.querySelector(targetNode) != null) {
                //40px is the height of the bar
                document.querySelector(targetNode).style.setProperty("top", "calc(100% - 40px)");
                //after action is done, disconnect the observer from the nodetree
                observerGoogleTranslator.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
};
// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observerGoogleTranslator = new MutationObserver(lowerGoogleTranslateBar);
// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observerGoogleTranslator.observe(nodetree, config);
```

You can learn more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver